# making a list of lists and strings into a flat list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have the following lista that contains lists and strings:

```
[['i','love','you'],['i','like','you']]
```

I would like to make it a list with this output:

```
["i love you", "i like you"]
```

Probably I might not be using the correct keywords to find the desired answer(Using python).how to  solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.join()` to flatten a single list into a string. Then use list comprehension to iterate over all the lists.

```
inp = [['i','love','you'],['i','like','you']]

outp = [' '.join(i) for i in inp]

print(outp)

>>> ['i love you', 'i like you']
```

Answer (score 0):

The same function as in the other answer, but uses mapping:

```
strings = [['i','love','you'],['i','like','you']]
list(map(" ".join, strings))
#['i love you', 'i like you']
```